# How to plot a contour plot of two classes in R given the mean, variance and mixing proportion of each class?

Tags: r

I have used mvnormalmixEM from the mixtools package in R to get the mean, variance and mixing proportions of a dataset consisting of two clusters. I need to create a contour plot of this with the original data points visible. My code so far:

```
model <- mvnormalmixEM(data, k=2)

plot(
    x = model,
    whichplots = 2
)
```

This produces a plot of the data with singular rings around the means of the clusters, with the ring diameter representing the variance, however this is not a contour plot.

Comment: Hi there, we cant reproduce your figure because we dont have your data. Could you try posting the structure with something like `dput()`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.